# Javascript doesn't affect html code added with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, append, jquery

I'm using jquery and [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) to upload photos to server. After uploading photos they are added to a div container using ajax. Everything works great except DELETE button. All delete buttons work on page load but those added via ajax don't work. I suppose that's because I defined function that enables image deletion and didn't use 'classic' way of deleting (form deletion):

```
// Delete photo              
    $(".blog_slike .delete_slika").click(function() {
        var commentContainer = $(this).parent().parent();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var string = 'id='+ id ;

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "./include/ajax-edit/delete.php?polje=blog_slika",
           data: string,
           cache: false,
           success: function(){
            commentContainer.fadeOut("slow");
            $('#load').fadeOut();
           }       
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Any idea how to make button work after it's added to html code using `append()` function?

One more thing... to add photos to tinymce editor I use this function:

```
<a href=\"javascript:;\" onmousedown=\"tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'$slike_u_sadrzaj');\">Ubaci sve slike u blog</a>
```

...which was also added on page load. How can I add content to place where is `$slike_u_sadrzaj` located and how to delete it?

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the jquery `live` method.

> Added in jQuery 1.3: Binds a handler to an event (like click) for all current - and future - matched element. Can also bind custom events.

[jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

Sample code:

```
  $(".blog_slike .delete_slika").live('click',function() {
```

Comment: Great! That's it, thanks! One more thing... How to make button fade? This is current code: $(".blog_slike .delete_slika").fadeTo("fast", 0.3); I tried this: $(".blog_slike .delete_slika").live(function() {fadeTo("fast", 0.3)}; But no success..

Comment: Live is only for events. Use CSS for opacity or call a jQuery after creating a new element.

Comment: I see... How to call jQuery after creating new element? What exactly do you mean by that? Thanks

Comment: "After uploading photos they are added to a div container using ajax." I mean when they are added.

Comment: I understood that, but how do you mean to call jQuery after adding element. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I'll survive without fade effect :)
Thanks anyway

Comment: You are welcome :) I would appreciate if you could accept my post as the right answer.